# Is it possible to render an Angular Component that is sent from a Serverless function (e.g. Lambda on AWS)?

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-lambda, server-side-rendering

I have a SPA written in JS using the Angular 6 Framework and I would like to dynamically render an Angular Component that sits on a remote server.

I am currently using `viewContainerRef` to render dynamically components that are sitting inside my project, but the idea is to extract all these components and put those on remote servers.

I tried with `innerHTML`, but this is not powerful enough.

I believe that the way to go would be to look at universal apps, but I m not sure about it.

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: Here is a lin to guide how to generate dynamic  components https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36

Answer (score 0):

For those interested.

I basically followed this blog from [Manfred Stayer](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx) where he explains how to create an external Angular component that can then be loaded from the Web.

Just follow the steps from the blog and then once your build the project, you will be left with a single bundle.js file containing the project you have built. I decided to put this file on a public S3 bucket that can be retrieved at any time as follows:

**Load script**

```
load(url, cb): void {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url; // s3 path
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    cb();
  }
```

**Create element**

```
  // load app from url
  loadAppComponent(url, identifier, data) {
    this.externalService.load(url, () => {
      const component = document.createElement(identifier);
      component.setAttribute('data', JSON.stringify(data));
      const content = document.getElementById('content');
      content.appendChild(component);
    });
  }
```

For more details, check the blog from [Manfred Stayer](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx)!